# How do I stop links from wrapping in DNN 4.9.x

Tags: hyperlink, word-wrap, dotnetnuke

I am having a problem with links wrapping. How do I prevent this?

![Wordwrap][1]

[1]:

Comment: Could you give a specific example?  Screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the `<nobr>` tag.

for example:

```
<nobr><a href="#">my long link</a></nobr>
```

Comment: My question is where do I apply the <nobr>?